# WMS layer as basemap in Configurable Map Viewer (CMV)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, configurable-map-viewer

My goal is to use both wms layers and arcgis tiled layers as basemaps. I have accomplished this before in a separate application by simply adding it to the map as a layer and reordering the selected 'basemap' layer to 0.

**EDIT:** I recently revisited this and found a more simplistic solution. This works in both 'custom' and 'agol' mode. No changes to Controller.js are required.

basemaps.js

```
define([

    'esri/layers/WMSLayer',
    'esri/layers/WMSLayerInfo',
    'esri/geometry/Extent'
], function (WMSLayer, WMSLayerInfo, Extent) {
    return {
        map: true, // needs a refrence to the map
        mode: 'agol', //must be either 'agol' or 'custom'
        title: 'Basemaps', // tilte for widget
        mapStartBasemap: 'hybrid', // must match one of the basemap keys below
        //basemaps to show in menu. define in basemaps object below and reference by name here
        // TODO Is this array necessary when the same keys are explicitly included/excluded below?

        basemapsToShow: ['hybrid','streets','topo', 'Natural2015','Infrared2015', 'Natural2013', 'Natural2012', 'Infrared2012', 'Natural2010', 'Natural2007', 'Infrared2007'],

        // a WMS configuration (WMSLayer): This setup currently only supports one wms server.
        wmsConfig: new WMSLayer('http://geodata.state.nj.us/imagerywms/Natural2015?', {
            id: 'wmslayer',
            resourceInfo: {
                extent: new Extent({
                    'xmin': -166753.95750000002,
                    'ymin': 1423.4125000000931,
                    'xmax': 1100824.1675,
                    'ymax': 997517.1625000001,
                    'spatialReference': {
                        'wkid': 3424
                    }
                }),
                layerInfos: [new WMSLayerInfo({
                    title: 'Imagery'
                })],
                version: ['1.1.1']
            },
            visibleLayers: []
        }),

        // define all valid custom basemaps here. Object of Basemap objects. For custom basemaps, the key name and basemap id must match.
        basemaps: { // agol basemaps
            streets: {
                title: 'Streets'
            },
            hybrid: {
                title: 'Hybrid'
            },
            topo: {
                title: 'Topo'
            },


            // examples of WMS layers
            Natural2015: {
                title: '2015 - Leaf Off (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Natural2015'
                }
            },

            Infrared2015: {
                title: '2015 - Infrared (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Infrared2015'
                }
            },

            Natural2013: {
                title: '2013 - Leaf On (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Natural2013'
                }
            },

            Natural2012: {
                title: '2012 - Leaf Off (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Natural2012'
                }
            },

            Infrared2012: {
                title: '2012 - Infrared (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Infrared2012'
                }
            },

            Natural2010: {
                title: '2010 - Leaf On (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Natural2010'
                }
            },

            Natural2007: {
                title: '2007 - Leaf Off (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Natural2007'
                }
            },

            Infrared2007: {
                title: '2007 - Infrared (WMS)',
                wms: true,
                basemap :{
                    id: 'Infrared2007'
                }
            }

        }
    };
});
```

Basemaps.js

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
    'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
    'dojo/_base/lang',
    'dijit/DropDownMenu',
    'dijit/MenuItem',
    'dojo/_base/array',
    'dojox/lang/functional',
    'dojo/text!./Basemaps/templates/Basemaps.html',
    'esri/dijit/BasemapGallery',
    'dojo/i18n!./Basemaps/nls/resource',

    'dijit/form/DropDownButton',
    'xstyle/css!./Basemaps/css/Basemaps.css'
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, lang, DropDownMenu, MenuItem, array, functional, template, BasemapGallery, i18n) {

    // main basemap widget
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        widgetsInTemplate: true,
        i18n: i18n,
        mode: 'agol',
        title: i18n.title,
        //baseClass: 'gis_Basemaps_Dijit',
        //buttonClass: 'gis_Basemaps_Button',
        //menuClass: 'gis_Basemaps_Menu',
        mapStartBasemap: 'streets',
        basemapsToShow: ['streets', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'topo', 'gray', 'oceans', 'national-geographic', 'osm'],
        validBasemaps: [],
        postCreate: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.currentBasemap = this.mapStartBasemap || null;

            var WMSLayer = this.wmsConfig;

            //WMS loading indicator for basemaps dropdown
            WMSLayer.on('update-start', lang.hitch(this, function () {
                this.dropDownButton.set('iconClass', 'fa fa-refresh fa-spin');
            }));

            WMSLayer.on('update-end', lang.hitch(this, function () {
                this.dropDownButton.set('iconClass', 'basemapsIcon');
            }));

            if (this.mode === 'custom') {
                this.gallery = new BasemapGallery({
                    map: this.map,
                    showArcGISBasemaps: false,
                    basemaps: functional.map(this.basemaps, function (map) {
                        return map.basemap;
                    })
                });
                // if (this.map.getBasemap() !== this.mapStartBasemap) { //based off the title of custom basemaps in viewer.js config
                //     this.gallery.select(this.mapStartBasemap);
                // }
                this.gallery.startup();
            }

            this.menu = new DropDownMenu({
                style: 'display: none;' //,
                //baseClass: this.menuClass
            });

            array.forEach(this.basemapsToShow, function (basemap) {

                if (this.basemaps.hasOwnProperty(basemap)) {
                    var menuItem = new MenuItem({
                        id: basemap,
                        label: this.basemaps[basemap].title,
                        iconClass: (basemap == this.mapStartBasemap) ? 'selectedIcon' : 'emptyIcon',
                        onClick: lang.hitch(this, function () {
                            var wms = this.basemaps[basemap].wms;
                            if (basemap !== this.currentBasemap) {
                                this.currentBasemap = basemap;
                                if (this.mode === 'custom' && !wms) {
                                    this.map.removeLayer(WMSLayer);
                                    this.gallery.select(basemap);
                                }
                                else if (this.mode === 'agol' && !wms) {
                                    this.map.removeLayer(WMSLayer);
                                    this.map.setBasemap(basemap);
                                }
                                else if (this.mode === 'custom' && wms){
                                    this.map.addLayer(WMSLayer, 1);
                                    this.wmsConfig.setVisibleLayers(this.basemaps[basemap].basemap.id);
                                    this.map.setBasemap(null);
                                }
                                else if (this.mode === 'agol' && wms){
                                    this.map.addLayer(WMSLayer, 1);
                                    this.wmsConfig.setVisibleLayers(this.basemaps[basemap].basemap.id);
                                }

                                var ch = this.menu.getChildren();
                                array.forEach(ch, function (c) {
                                    if (c.id == basemap) {
                                        c.set('iconClass', 'selectedIcon');
                                    } else {
                                        c.set('iconClass', 'emptyIcon');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        })
                    });
                    this.menu.addChild(menuItem);
                }
            }, this);

            this.dropDownButton.set('dropDown', this.menu);
        },
        startup: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            if (this.mode === 'custom') {
                if (this.map.getBasemap() !== this.mapStartBasemap) { //based off the title of custom basemaps in viewer.js config
                    this.gallery.select(this.mapStartBasemap);
                }
            } else {
                if (this.mapStartBasemap) {
                    if (this.map.getBasemap() !== this.mapStartBasemap) { //based off the agol basemap name
                        this.map.setBasemap(this.mapStartBasemap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it's possibile to see what are you modify the code for set wms into custom basemap and set it?
I'm trying to do the same your operation. Thanks

Comment: Yes I can post it later tonight.

Comment: btw this code works, i am just unable to remove the starting basemap.